# What are the limits of my definite integral if the domain of my function is less than and not equal to?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have just started learning integration and I am a bit confused on the limits of my definite integral. If the domain of f(x) is (0 ≤ x < 1), would the limits of my definite integral be
$$\int_0^1 f(x) dx$$ or would it be
$$\int_0^{0.9999999} f(x) dx$$

Comment: $\int_0^1 f(x) dx.$

Comment: If $x=1$ is not in the domain, then the integral would be $\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: so then would it be ok to do $\int_0^1 f(x) dx.$

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the area under the curve $f(x)$ from $0$ to $1$ and not including $1$. You could think of that as the:

"area under $f(x)$ from $0$ to $1$" $-$ "area under $f(x)$ **AT** $1$"

= $$\int_0^1f(x)dx-\int_1^1f(x)dx$$
$$=\int_0^1f(x)dx-0$$
Does that help?

Comment: That clarifies my question. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help!